# Upper, lower, left and right Riemann sums for $\int_{-1}^{3} x^2dx$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve this question:

> Write the upper, lower, left and right Riemann sums for the following
>    integral, 
>    using 4 equal subintervals:
>
> $\int_{-1}^{3} x^2dx$

Comment: What have you tried? For a Riemann sum, you need 2 things: a) the subintervals, b) the value of $f$ corresponding to your each of the questions. If you have a graph of $x^2$ in the interval $[-1,3]$, you should be able to answer each of the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

You basically have to do exactly what is done here. Since you have 4 equal subintervalls those are [-1,0],[0,1], [1,2] and [2,3]. The function f is in your case given by $x^2$.